# Are VPN's illegal in Saudi Arabia?

Tags: saudi-arabia

I may have to expend extended periods of time in Riyadh, Saudi Arabia. This is a country with strong censorship, even blocking WhatsApp calls or Discord.

I am aware that in my home country I do a bunch of things online that would get swiftly blocked as well. So if I want to go there, I will have to use a VPN, as it's the only way I won't feel fear from the government's gaze.

So, is installing a VPN previous to entering the country and using it inside illegal?

After a thorough search I just found [some dude's blog](https://lifeinsaudiarabia.net/is-it-safe-to-use-vpn-services-in-saudi/#Can_I_use_VPN_Service_in_Saudi_Arabia) defending his country beliefs without any proof and many tech pages affirming they are legal just [to advertise them later](https://www.comparitech.com/blog/vpn-privacy/is-vpn-legal-saudi-arabia/).

Answer (score 2):

There does not appear to be a direct "statutory" ban no possession or use of a VPN in KSA, instead the government blocks access to VPN connections. There may well be laws against activities which motivate using a VPN, you can check the cyber crimes law [here](https://www.mcit.gov.sa/sites/default/files/anti_cyber_crime_law_en_0.pdf). KSA differs from UAE, where [using a VPN is illegal](https://wired.me/technology/privacy/vpns-legal-uae-saudi-arabia/) ("fraudulent computer network protocol address" used in the commission of a crime).